# Pretty URLs only partially working correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink, friendly-url

With a bit of help from people here at Stackoverflow I've managed to put together a .htaccess file that permits 'pretty URLs'. This is great if a user types the 'pretty URL' directly into the address bar as the conversion works exactly as I would like it to do, but if a user clicks a link within my site that generates a dynamic link, the 'ugly URL' remains and the conversion doesn't take place. Is there something I need to add to the .htaccess file to get this to work, or do I need to code up some PHP to force the conversion for links?

My .htaccess file is set-up as follows:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^episode/(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$ /episode.php?episode=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(Converts `http://mysite.com/episode.php?episode=31` to `http://mysite.com/episode/31`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append this rule in the end to force pretty URL in browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+episode\.php\?episode=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ episode/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Once working change `R=302` to `R=301`.